# ¿Cómo obtengo el número más alto con having?

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
Fecha       Cuenta      Estatus
02/05/20    345           1
02/05/20    345           9
03/05/20    678           4
03/05/20    345           3
03/05/20    345           8
```

La regla es solo obtener los estatus 1, 4, 8 por cada cuenta. Y en el caso en donde en el mismo día se obtengan dos estatus de los “permitidos” (1,4,8), solo extraer el más alto, es decir, en este caso:

```
Fecha       Cuenta      Estatus
03/05/20    678         4
03/05/20    345         3
03/05/20    345         8
```

Solo debería obtener la fila de estatus 8.

Intente el siguiente **query**:

```
Select fecha, cuenta, estatus
From  cuentas
Group by fecha, cuenta, estatus
Having max(estatus) in (1,4,8)
Order by cuenta.
```

La obtención de cuentas solo con estatus 1, 4 y 8 sí funciona, pero cuando hay dos cuentas en una misma fecha no logro extraer la de estatus mayor.

Comment: saca el estatus del group by, y en el select ponele max(estatus)

Comment: ah y saca ese having

Comment: El having me ayuda a discriminar los estatus diferentes a 1,4 y 8 y el max en el select no funciona ya que no siempre necesito el máximo

Comment: segun lo que escribiste si necesitas el max... el having deberia ser un where... entonces explica con un buen ejemplo porque el max no sirve...

Comment: Lo que te dice gonzalo, es que lo que has escrito en tu pregunta se resuelve así: `Select fecha, cuenta, max(estatus) From  cuentas Group by fecha, cuenta Order by cuenta`, a no ser que sea otra cosa lo que estás buscando. Saludos.

Comment: No, eso consideraría todos los estatus. En primera el estatus no se puede sacar del grupo by al menos a mí me manda error, además que hay estatus que no quiero que aparezcan. Y por último también está el tema de las fechas. Quiero que se presente el estatus más alto solo si las fechas son iguales.

Comment: Agrega un  `where` para filtrar solo los estatus que quieras, hay algo que se me escapa, por que la consulta que te pasé hace exactamente lo que dices, el último estatus por cada fecha y cuenta. Si usas `max(estatus)`, puedes sacarlo del `group by`

Comment: Cierto Patricio,  tuve que hacer una pequeña modificación ya que está es una subconsulta pero me ayudaste muchisimo. Muchas gracias por todo!!

Answer (score 0):

Oscar,

Con esta consulta vas a obtener el resultado que buscas:

```
SELECT fecha, cuenta, MAX(estatus) estatus
FROM   d
WHERE estatus IN (1,4,8) 
GROUP  BY fecha, cuenta
ORDER BY 1, 2;

FECHA                  CUENTA                                ESTATUS                               
2020-05-02             345                                   1                                     
2020-05-03             345                                   8                                     
2020-05-03             678                                   4
```

En un query primero se evalua la condicion del WHERE, por lo tanto el universo que se observa al agrupar esta formado solamente sobre aquellos registros con estatus (1, 4, 8). Los registros que estan en otro estado se excluyen al inicio.

En este otro query (**con el que no obtienes lo que buscas**), al no tener un filtro en el WHERE, participan todos los registros. Pero solo forman parte del resultado aquellos cuyos valores maximos de estatus estan dentro de (1, 4, 8)

```
SELECT fecha, cuenta, MAX(estatus) estatus
FROM   d
GROUP  BY fecha, cuenta
HAVING MAX(estatus) IN (1,4,8) 
ORDER BY 1, 2; 

FECHA                  CUENTA                                ESTATUS                               
2020-05-03             345                                   8                                     
2020-05-03             678                                   4
```

Esto no es muy ortodoxo pero te servira pensar la seccion de HAVING como un WHERE del GROUP BY.

Espero que te sirva.
Saludos.